# First/last elements of ActiveRecord_Relation as relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I perform a query like, for example:

```
CarrotTopProps.where(funny: false)
```

which returns an ActiveRecord_Relation object.

Now, I need the first, say, 10 results of that query, I can write:

```
CarrotTopProps.where(funny: false).first(10)
```

but that will give me an Array object. Crazy as it might sound, I need the resulting object to maintain the ActiveRecord_Relation class.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `limit` and - if you want the "first" objects, combine it with `order`.

```
CarrotTopProps.where(funny: false).limit(10)
```

yields an ActiveRecord::Relation

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-limit